# Populating a Treeview in wpf

Tags: sql, wpf, populate

I have a SQL table like the following:

```
NodeID--ParentID--NodeText
    1            1                N1
    2            1                N11
    3            1                N12
    4            2                N111
    5            2                N112
    6            5                N1121
    7            5                N1122
    8            7                N11221
    etc...
```

Can anyone please tell me or point me to some resources that show me how to populate a treeview from the SQL data in wpf?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
// Fill your dataset here
ds.Relations.Add("YourRelationName", ds.Tables[0].Columns["ParentColumnName"], ds.Tables[0].Columns["ChildColumnName"]);
treeView.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

write a HierarchicalDataTemplate for the TreeView and bind it in XAML as

```
<TreeView Name="treeView">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeText}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding YourRelationName}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeText}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```